# How can I search a file I open and check to see if user's input is located inside? Then print the neighboring elements

Tags: python, list, file, search, split

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x87dl.png)

Here is an example of the code I have. The code is saved in the file as:

pizza

100

100

100

I want the user to input the word 'pizza' and I want the program to search the file and print the next 3 elements.

Comment: Please do not attach pictures of code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the file food.txt in your directory (name can be changed)

```
def file_search(food, file="food.txt"):
    count = 0
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if count >= 3:
                break

            if line.strip() == food or count:
                print(line.strip())
                count += 1


file_search(input("Food --> "))
```